# What is the best way to align these elements on the page?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, css

What would be the best way to align the boxes seen here:

http://property.begbies-traynor.com

The boxes in question are the 'Further Details' boxes. I would like them all to line up perfectly on the page regardless of the description length.

Would it be best to use CSS? JS? Or hardcoded php?

The site is wordpress based using a custom theme.

Answer (score 3):

Set each one of your containers, such as:

`<div class="post-3283 sale type-sale status-publish hentry ts-box box-4 clear">`

To have an additional class, and in that, set:

`height:370px;`
`position:relative;`

Then, give each `<p>` that holds a green button a class, and give that the rule:

`position:absolute;`
`bottom:0;`

You can test this by setting `ts-box` to have those added rules, and a giving a single `p` the latter positioning rules.

**EDIT:** Here is a Fiddle illustrating the concept. Ignore the `float`, `width`, and `border` attributes, they are just for conceptualizing: http://jsfiddle.net/aTtAW/

Answer (score 0):

CSS would be my best bet. You could have a fixed height for the description box with overflow hidden (so that any extra description text will be hidden) and right below the description box have another div to hold the 'Further Details' box. That way all the 'Further Details' box will be in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

give a class to the description container and set a height to it in css

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, maybe add a small code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I would pick CSS `min-height` attribute for that `<p>` and set it to `100-200`. This will let exceptionally long text to heighten the box, but usually you will have nice aligned buttons.

Do not hide text with `overflow`. It's ugly.